# Marriage and annulments

Tags: catholicism, marriage, annulment

I am a Catholic that was married in the Episcopal Church 25 years ago.
My wife and I have had a civil dissolution 8 years ago.
Does the Catholic church consider my marriage valid, and requires an annulment, or was
it never valid in the first place?

Comment: Hi Tim! Have you searched for "annulment" or "Catholic marriage" here? Did you find anything close? I'm almost positive I've answered a very similar question.

Comment: Note: If there's something unanswered, we'll need a bit more information to give a definitive answer here.

Comment: The question seems confused. A valid marriage can't be annulled.  An annulment is an official certification that the alleged marriage was never valid in the first place.